# How to get different tax for a product in different store view magento2?

Tags: magento2, multistore, tax, store-view, tax-class

I am working on **magento2**. I need to get **different tax** for a product in different store view.
For example:
I need to get:
Tax Class of product A in store 1 is Taxable Goods.
Tax Class of product A in store 2 is None.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is right.
Since magento allows the price to be global or at website level, taxes (and everything else price relate) should be the same. Global or at website level.
But if you want you can change the scope of the attribute `tax_class_id` to 0 (store view).
The scope of the attribute is kept in the table `catalog_eav_attribute` in the column `is_global`.
The id of the attribute you need to change you can find it like this:

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'tax_class_id';
```

Comment: thanks. Is it simple to change the scope of tax class to store view by create a module?